# not waiting an asynchronous action ? Discord python bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot but I am having trouble figuring how the async/await works and how to solve my issue.

**So here is what I am trying to do :**

My bot sends a message saying something like "I am launching a 10 minutes timer if you want to stop it click on the emoji bellow" and then adds an emoji to the message. Then it starts a function that sleeps for 10 minutes. If the user clicks on the emoji it is catch by the "on_reaction_add" which stops the waiting (actually it updates a boolean). If the user doesn't click on any emoji, at the end of the 10 minutes my bot sends a message saying "Timer's up".

**The Problem :**

I can figure out how to make the timer not stop the entire program while it runs (it actually blocks the "on_reaction_add").

- I tried making the sleep function "async" but if I don't "await" it then I doesn't get launch at all.
- After that I tried putting the function in a Thread but when the timer ends it need to send a message saying "Timer's up" which is an async function so I need to await it again, however if I await it then my whole function needs to be async (Why tho ? If I am awaiting for something asynchronous shouldn't I be synchronous ?) and then I run in the same problem as before.

Here are the pieces of code I tried :

```py
t1 = Thread(target=SetTimer, args=[bs, channel, round])

t1=Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(SetTimer(bs, channel, round),))
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

```py
# --- DISCORD ---
import discord
import time

ended = False
async def SetTimer(channel):
    print("lets wait")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("waiting ended")
    await End(channel)

async def End(channel):
    if ended == True:
        return
    ended = True
    await channel.send("This is the end")

TOKEN = "XXXXXXX"
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as' + str(self.user.name))
        print('The chatbot Id :: ' + str(self.user.id))
    async def on_message(self, message):
        an_str = "Ok Let's start the timer\nClick on :white_check_mark: when you want to end it !"
        answer = await message.channel.send(an_str)
        await answer.add_reaction('✅')

        #Here start timer :
        SetTimer(message.channel)
    
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        if reaction.message.author != client.user:
            return
        if reaction.message.content.startswith("Ok Let's start a") and reaction.count>1 and reaction.emoji == '✅':
            await End(reaction.message.channel)
```

I am totally stuck, I am not getting the async/await stuff yet and it shows.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Please provide more details of your source code.

Comment: @Soumendra I added an example for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your bot to freeze, use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`.

> I tried making the sleep function "async" but if I don't "await" it then I doesn't get launch at all.

Yes, that's how async/await works.

> After that I tried putting the function in a Thread

Don't use threads for this, it's way overkill & overcomplicates things. `asyncio.sleep` does the job.

> if I await it then my whole function needs to be async (Why tho ? If I am awaiting for something asynchronous shouldn't I be synchronous ?)

No, awaiting something can only be done in an asynchronous function. `await` suspends your program & gives control back to the event loop so that it can come back to it later on - when the function is done running. This is an asynchronous action.

```py
async def some_function():
    # At this point you're basically saying
    # "Go do something else until g is done running, then continue"
    await g()
```

You may want to read up on async a bit more before attempting a project like this. Discord.py isn't beginner-friendly.

Comment: ```python
import time

#So by saying async, I am telling "this function needs to be launch asynchronously"
async def function():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("2")

print("1")
await function()
print("3")
```

As you say when I do async and await I am saying "Go do something else until g is done running, then continue". However in this exemple, why doesn't it go do something else ? From what I understand it should print : 1, 3, 2
But it doesn't do that, I don't understand why

Comment: Also I don't think discord isn't beginner friendly (or maybe I am not anymore). It is really amusing and very well documented (good doc is such a pleasure) the only thing giving me a though time is the idea behind await/async.

Comment: No, you're confusing coroutines with launching a thread. Your code still executes top to bottom, so `print("3")` only executes after `await function()` came back. The outer function will also stop running - what happens is the _event loop_ now regains control and can do whatever it wants (eg. run other coroutines). Your code won't start running in random order - that wouldn't work either way because you would never be able to use the return value of an async function.